# Integration by parts or substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{}^{}x e^x \mathrm dx$$

One of my friends said substitution , but I can't seem to get it to work.
Otherwise I also tried integration by parts but I'm not getting the same answer as wolfram.

The space in the question seems like it shouldn't take more than 2 lines though. Am I missing something?

Thanks to all the answers below , I messed up in the original question it was actually

$$\int_{}^{}x e^{x^2} \mathrm dx$$

With help from the below answers I did the following:

Let $u = x^2$ , then $du=2x\mathrm dx$

So rewriting the integral

$$\int_{}^{}{{x\cdot e^u} {1 \over 2x}} \mathrm dx$$

Simplifying yields:

$${1 \over 2x}\int_{}^{}{e^u}\mathrm dx$$

Which in turn yields:

$${\frac{e^u}{2}} + C$$

The rest is fairly obvious!

Comment: Integration by parts is never wrong when you're dealing with $\text{Polynomials}\times \exp$ or $\text{Polynomials} \times \text{Trig Function}$.

Comment: Your comment gave me hope up until the point I read your nick :-) Thanks for the advice ^-^

Comment: Take solace in the fact that I too read my screen name.

Comment: If you want to find an anti-derivative of $x\mapsto xe^{x^2}$, note that this function almost looks like $u'(\exp \circ \,u)$, for some function $u$.

Comment: I edited my question to include the mistake and how I got to the answer ^-^ I left the faulty question too though because it's nice seeing how the one I was asking in particular is an exception.

Comment: You're a good member. Welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely by parts, as substitution of $x$ won't get you anywhere.
Let $u=e^x$ and $dv=e^x$ in $\int udv=uv-\int vdu$
and we have

$$ 
\int xe^xdx=xe^x-\int e^x dx=xe^x-e^x+c
$$

As a general tip, you will usually want to use parts if you have an exponential, which doesn't get any nastier as you anti-differentiate, and a polynomial which will disappear after some number of differentiations. A notable exception is when you have something like
$$
\int xe^{x^2}dx
$$
Where a $u=x^2$ substitution will cancel out the $x$ coefficient on the exponential.

Comment: You must have been sent from the heavens! I actually messed up the question it's missing the $e^x^2$! Thank you!

Comment: 4 minutes , I tried 2 minutes ago though xD

Comment: I trust your happy now though... I sure am :p

Comment: I am! And way to answer your own question.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can solve it by substitution (which is not trivial in this case) but you can choose:
$$u = e^x(x-1) \rightarrow du=xe^xdx\rightarrow dx=\dfrac{du}{xe^x}$$ 
Replacing in the integral, you get:
$$\int{xe^x \mathrm dx}= \int{du=u+C=e^x(x-1)}+C$$

**NOTE** the easiest way to solve the integrals in this form ($P_1(x)e^x$) is by using *integration by parts*

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by parts $$\int { x{ e }^{ x }dx }  =\int { xd{ e }^{ x } } =x{ e }^{ x }-\int { { e }^{ x }dx } ={ e }^{ x }\left( x-1 \right) +C$$